# Issue displaying Unity scene in airconsole developers console when launched from editor

Tags: airconsole

I'm having problems getting the Unity scene to display in the developers console when I launch it from the Unity editor. I'm running the basic scene provided with the Unity plugin.

Here's what I see on the developer console

[image]

If I build the project and launch as "Open Exported Port" I am not having the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Running OSX 10.10.3, Chrome 45.0.2454.85 and Unity 5.2.0f3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running your game from the editor, the browser window serves mainly to connect your controllers. The scene is displayed in the game window of the Unity Editor.

Edit: To avoid this confusion in the future, we've updated the plugin to tell you that the scene can be viewed in the editor.